When is a subset of a simply connected space $E$, simply connected?
It seems to not be generally true that a subset $U$ of a simply connected space $E$, is simply connected. The most obvious example perhaps is that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is simply connected, but that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is not simply connected (take any loop going around $(0,0)$).
Are there further assumptions one can impose on either $E$ (e.g. locally path-connected/connected) and/or $U$ under (e.g. component/path-component of $E$) under which one can say that $U$ will be simply connected?

As you note, you can poke a hole in pretty much any simply connected set and arrive at something that is not simply connected.  But poking a hole in a set doesn't have that much effect on other topological properties, particularly local properties (which generally won't even see the hole).  I don't know how you can do much better than "A subspace of a simply connected space is simply connected if and only if it is simply connected."

If you look in $\mathbb R^3$, and you set the vast complexity of non-simply connected subsets next to the vast complexity of simply connected subsets, perhaps an answer of No becomes appropriate to your question of "Are there further assumptions..." I would say that this question is really too vague to have any more reasonable answer.

See for instance my answer here. But try to narrow down your question to something answerable.

See also the answer here. But keep in mind that for every $n$ there is a Cantor subset $K\subset \mathbb R^n$ whose complement is not simply connected.

Note that a necessary condition is that the space is hereditarily connected. Would it be sufficient?

Hereditarily connected spaces are path connected. Are they simply connected to? https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Hereditarily+connected%2B%7ESimply+connected

@StevenClontz: Your edits have changed the question to a completely different question.

I don't think so. The spirit of the question was about guaranteeing when subspaces of simply connected are simply connected.

Of course, OP can correct me if I'm mistaken.

I believe you're discussing the hereditarily connected spaces, which are characterized by having a topology totally ordered by the subset relation. https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000196 Every subspace of such a space is in turn hereditarily connected and path connected.
I will show a hereditarily connected space has a trivial fundamental group. Given a loop, we may identify a minimum and maximal point with regards to the topology order. We may reparameterize points so the maximum point occurs at ±1 and the minimum point occurs at 0, and each point between is reached at ±t.  Finally, we may continuously deform the loop to a point by maxing out the loop at ±(1-t) from 0 to 1.
(On phone so I'm waiving my hands a bit; if I'm not overlooking an error I'll follow up to justify details if no one beats me to out.)
Edit: a more robust answer to this question is here. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5000543/86887
